# bootstrap 3-column with container in the center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

is it possible to have layout like this with bootstrap 3?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O31v.jpg

basically three column with class container in the center (2nd column). The 1st and 3rd column should take the remaining space between container and browser screen.

```
<div> //should be 100% width
    <div id="column1"></div>
    <div id="column2" class="container"></div> //maxed out at 1170px width
    <div id="column3"></div>
</div>
```

I need 1st and 3rd column as design elements (some kind of shadow overlay), which I can't add without affecting the middle container and overall responsiveness.

my idea is using javascript approach, but is there anything simpler and clean using bootstrap(3) or css?

Comment: Use row-fluid for responsive design and add 3 divs with classes span3, span6, span3...then apply a gradient to the first and the last div to get a shadow effect...

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
    <div class='col-lg-3'>3</div>
    <div class='col-lg-6'>6</div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'>3</div>
</body>
```

Don't wrap them in a container, just in the body tags, it should take the full width of the page.

Comment: Think you'd need to encase those `col`'s in a `<div class="row" />` too.

Comment: @MackieeE this creates a problem adding `row` as the width is too large for the screen creating a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Indeed you're right =) (Because of the negative margins the row add, not the width so much)

Comment: in my case, the middle div needs to be .container

Comment: There isn't a method to do this in bootstrap @user2813435 without having to do more queries for smaller sizes.